# Mysql Selecting Alias Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I Need to filter the query that have some conditional column as below:

```
 SELECT
     `c`.`fullname` AS `fullname`,
     IFNULL(`c`.`new_ic`,`c`.`old_ic`) AS `Ic`,
     `bla`.`loan_no` AS `Loan_No`,
     `bla`.`total_loan_amt` AS `Total_Loan_Amt`,
     `bla`.`monthly_installment` AS `Month_Inst_Amt`,
     `bla`.`disb_date` AS `disb_date` FROM (`customers` `c`
 JOIN `basic_loan_application` `bla`
    ON ((`bla`.`customer_uid` = `c`.`customer_uid`))) 
 WHERE Ic LIKE '%800%' ORDER BY `bla`.`Basic_Loan_Application_Id` DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

But I cannot Use the Ic Field  and return error as decribed below:

```
 Unknown column 'Ic' in 'where clause'
```

I want try to avoid **nested select** if possible.

Is there another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just repeat the definition:

```
WHERE IFNULL(`c`.`new_ic`,`c`.`old_ic`) LIKE '%800%'
ORDER BY `bla`.`Basic_Loan_Application_Id` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Or, if you like, use a MySQL extension that allows you to do the filtering (in this case) using a `having` clause:

```
HAVING Ic LIKE '%800%'
ORDER BY `bla`.`Basic_Loan_Application_Id` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```